# Помощь с запросом - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

У меня есть входные данные:
`restaurant: { id: 7, label: 'Fregat' }`
`сustomer_id: 5`

Задача стоит "Сделать фильтр по ресторану и вернуть клиента с суммой заказов из нужного ресторана "

Есть таблицы `order` и `partner`, в order есть поля `partner_id` и `customer_id` (нет restaurant_id) (id ресторана, необходимо сверить с таблицы partners),

Мне необходимо проверить на `customer_id`, что я и делаю
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order WHERE customer_id`=`customer.id...`

Далее необходимо проверить в таблице `partners` нужного мне партнера по `partner_id` .. и у этого партнера поле `restaurants`(datatype: TEXT) с массивом ресторанов и из массива проверить нужный мне ресторан, если он есть то COUNT ++ и так проверяем с таблицы `order` каждый ордер на наличие правильно клиента и ресторана... т.е. клиенту необходимо собрать количество ордеров из нужного ресторана
[image: Таблица orderd][image: Таблица partner]

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169)

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: *Мне необходимо .. Далее необходимо ..* - бред. Всё делается одним запросом. На входе - условия отбора, на выходе - требуемый результат.

Comment: @Akina 
- на входе : есть customer_id,  restaurant_id, 
- на выходе: количество ордеров с restaurant_id.
У меня не получается сделать все это. По этому я тут и пишу. За некорректное или "непривычное" изложение мысли, уж приношу свои извинения.

Comment: Я дал Вам две ссылки. Прочитали? усвоили? приведите в порядок свой вопрос, сейчас с ним невозможно работать. *на входе : есть customer_id, restaurant_id* - это на входе где-то в программе, а нужно указать, что именно и в каком формате будет передаваться в запрос. *на выходе: количество ордеров с restaurant_id* - следует это показать именно в той форме, в какой это вернёт MySQL (в виде набора записей).